# Not Obtaining Expected Correlations with the IBM Synthetic Data Generator

Tags: data-mining, dataset, association-rules

I`m using IBM synthetic data generator to produce a transactional dataset, but i have some problems with the support of the item.

Example:

*C:\ >"IBM Quest Data Generator.exe" lit -ascii -ntrans 10 -corr 0.75 -nitems 1 > output.txt*

In this example I expected a data set with approximately 10.000 row with 1000 items and correlation about 75%. But it`s not happens. The great correlation that I found was 1.5%.

Another example was: -corr 75 , but didn`t change the correlation of the item. The follow example:

*C:\ >"IBM Quest Data Generator.exe" lit -ascii -ntrans 10 -corr 75 -nitems 1 > output.txt*

Why do all the items have support (correlation) lower that I expected?

Comment: Your orthography suggests you prefer to use "." as a decimal separator instead of ",".  In your locale is it possible that the "0.75" argument is being parsed as "0" and "75", with the latter ignored? That would produce correlations which fluctuate slightly around $0$.

Comment: i don't thing so, cause i have the source code and the default value for this variable is 0.25 .

Comment: I've been lookinhg for another program that works like ibm data generator... and i found ARTOOL [link](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~laur/ARtool/)... it's interesting and works. but i'm still trying to understand the IBM genetator...